# Things That Can Be Made In Shell Script?

Tags: scripts

So I just started using shell scripting, and was wondering what type of programs you can create. I want to continue using shell script, but if it doesn't lead to anywhere particularly useful I personally don't see the point in using it.

Comment: Batch renaming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602706/batch-renaming-with-bash which I use often

Answer (score 2):

Bash is [Turing-complete](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting#A_few_notes_on_terminology). You can implement anything in it that can be implemented in another Turing-complete language, such as Python or C.

Comment: Thanks, I had to read up on Turning-complete, but it helped me to understand a little bit more.